# Which stack exchange site do I post questions about hardware on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm trying to figure out if I should get a Roku or AppleTV, or some other competing device. I have some specific questions about supported video formats. What forum should I ask that question on?

I'm also trying to figure out what pair of Bose headphones would be the best. Is there a site for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product recommendations are not on-topic on any Stack Exchange site.  There's currently no site where you can ask specific questions about consumer electronics, but there is a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) for one on Area 51.